# How to enable share_item on a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have several FB Pages and are needing to post items to the pages. We're getting the error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#282) Requires extended permission: share_item.

I had the same error when I first posted to my personal FB page. But worked after I checked the "share_item" in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

The issue is, **how can I enable "share_item" on other FB pages that I'm a "manager" to?** Is there a page in the FB Menu that I'm not seeing or how do I use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer with those other pages to enable it?

The following code is what works once I've enabled the "share_item" on my personal FB page, however again the question is how do I enable share_item on a FB page that I'm a manager of?

`$fb = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
     'secret' => FB_SECRET,
));`

$fb->api( '/' . FB_PAGE_ID . '/links', 'POST', array(
     'client_id' => FB_APP_ID,
     'access_token' => $fb->getAccessToken(),
     'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
     'message' => 'Some comments...'
));

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) documentation again - your [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow must not be requesting the correct permissions from the users.

Request `publish_stream` permission - this encompasses all the other publishing permissions like `share_item`, `status_update`, etc. 
If this is a Page access token you're using it should already have the appropriate permissions

Comment: this didn't answer the question. My question is how to enable the share_item (or any permission) on a Facebook page that I'm a "manager" to in the Admin Roles. Thanks.

Comment: Then i'm not sure i understand your question - what permissions does your access token have? (a call to `/me/permissions` will show you) - are you sure you haven't forgotten to grant a publishing permission which allows that access token to make posts on your behalf?

Comment: We're asking for "how to grant any permission, but specifically the share_item permission, on a Facebook page that I'm a manager on."